# use loop through data json value and display each of it into card

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, for-loop

I have a problem in using loop since i didn't know what kind of loop to use in this case (sorry i'm still learning jquery & js!). In the result page I have created card to separate each data from json, but i'm stuck on how to display the data inside each card.Here is the breakdown:

> result example

[image: result_example]

> code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Display data json into cards</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">

        <div class="card-header"></div>

        <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>

            <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
            success: function (result) {

                $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                    var userId = item.userId; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                    var typeId = item.id; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                    var titleId = item.title; //this should be in h5 class = "card-title"
                    var bodyId = item.body; //this should be in p class = "card-text"

                    var html = '<div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">';
                        html += '<div class="card-header"></div>';
                        html += '<div class="card-body">';
                        html += '<h5 class="card-title"></h5>';
                        html += '<p class="card-text"></p>';
                        html += '</div>';
                        html += '</div>';
                        html += '</div>';

                    //use loop below here and inject to div.container    

                    $(".container").html(html); //using .html() will display one card,use loop to display each card

                });
                // console.log('success', result);
                // console.log(result[0].body);
                // console.log($(result).length);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for asking a bit much, and thank you for the help!

Comment: `html += '<p class="card-text">'+ bodyId +'</p>';` same idea with the others .. Is this what you want??

Comment: Yes it can be done like that, but the first div below div.container still display empty data while the div that created from var html being added. So what i thought is, it should be using loop to solve it

Comment: So that means no need for it?? remove it so before the ajax you can add `$('.container > div').remove();`

Comment: Also you can hide the first `div` using css `.container > div:eq(0){ display : none; }` .. and you still can do both this css and js remove

Comment: Okay i have tried it, and it works sir! But i have a bit more question if you don't mind.. So i have edited the code so the injection changed from $(".container").append(html) into $(".container").html(html) and it only display one card. To solve the problem I need to use loop right? If so could you explain how is the method for looping it? Appreciate the help sir!

Comment: You want to use a loop whatever what? :-) .. Nooo Noo loop needed please forget about loop .. `.each()` is enough .. see my answer below about  using `.html()`

Comment: Oooh i get it now.. Yeah i'm sorry sir with my obsession about loop xD Thanks a lot for the help sir, really appreciate it!

Comment: never mind  you're totally welcome :-) .. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

- You already have a loop by using `.each` the problem is you didn't pass/concatenate the variables in your js/html
- And about *but the first div below div.container still display empty data while the div that created from var html being added* you can use css or/and js to hide/remove it

**[1]** Using css,js `.append()`

```js
$(function () {
    $('.container > div').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                var userId = item.userId; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                var typeId = item.id; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                var titleId = item.title; //this should be in h5 class = "card-title"
                var bodyId = item.body; //this should be in p class = "card-text"

                var html = '<div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">';
                    html += '<div class="card-header">user: ' + userId +' typeId: '+ typeId +'</div>';
                    html += '<div class="card-body">';
                    html += '<h5 class="card-title">'+ titleId +'</h5>';
                    html += '<p class="card-text">'+ bodyId +'</p>';
                    html += '</div>';
                    html += '</div>';
                    html += '</div>';

                //use loop below here and inject to div.container    

                $(".container").append(html);

            });
            // console.log('success', result);
            // console.log(result[0].body);
            // console.log($(result).length);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.card:nth-child(1){
  display : none;
}
.card{
  margin : 20px;
  padding : 20px;
  background : #eee;
  border : 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">

        <div class="card-header"></div>

        <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>

            <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[2]** If you want to use `.html()` you need to define the `var html` before the `each()` then let the `.each` update the `html +=` value then use the `.html()` after the `.each()` <sup>I still prefer the first solution</sup>

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                var userId = item.userId; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                var typeId = item.id; //this should be in div class = "card-header"
                var titleId = item.title; //this should be in h5 class = "card-title"
                var bodyId = item.body; //this should be in p class = "card-text"

                html += '<div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">';
                    html += '<div class="card-header">user: ' + userId +' typeId: '+ typeId +'</div>';
                    html += '<div class="card-body">';
                    html += '<h5 class="card-title">'+ titleId +'</h5>';
                    html += '<p class="card-text">'+ bodyId +'</p>';
                    html += '</div>';
                    html += '</div>';
                    html += '</div>';

                //use loop below here and inject to div.container    

                
            });
            $(".container").html(html);

            // console.log('success', result);
            // console.log(result[0].body);
            // console.log($(result).length);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.card{
  margin : 20px;
  padding : 20px;
  background : #eee;
  border : 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">

        <div class="card-header"></div>

        <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>

            <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following solution:

To bind the variable inside the string use **``**

```
$(function() {
  var html = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    success: function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(index, item) {
        html +=
          '<div class="card bg-light border-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 70rem;">';
        html += `<div class="card-header">userid: ${item.userId} - id: ${item.id}</div>`;
        html += '<div class="card-body">';
        html += `<h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>`;
        html += `<p class="card-text">${item.body}</p>`;
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        //using .html() will display one card,use loop to display each card
      });
      $(".container").html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

And see the following in the stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xfs15o?file=index.html